# How do you search for files containing DOS line endings (CRLF) with grep on Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, newline

I want to search for files containing DOS line endings with grep on Linux.  Something like this:

```sh
grep -IUr --color '\r\n' .
```

The above seems to match for literal `rn` which is not what is desired.

The output of this will be piped through xargs into todos to convert crlf to lf like this

```
grep -IUrl --color '^M' . | xargs -ifile fromdos 'file'
```

Comment: Have you tried [dos2unix](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix)? It fixes line endings automatically.

Comment: I'm not quite sure but iirc there's a difference between quoting the pattern inside ' and ". Afaik in patterns enclosed in ' the escape sequences are interpreted as proper string so '\r' would be equivalent to "\\r" and "\r" has no equivalent (at least in that notation) with '.

Comment: Anticom: You're correct in this case that the difference between ' and " is irrelevant; however, generally they are distinct as ' surrounded strings are weak quoted, and " are strong quoted. The biggest thing I take advantage of is that $ expansions or `` don't expand in weak quoted strings. See [bash-hackers on quoting](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting) for more.

Comment: Easiest way is to use modern `dos2unix` with `-ic` switch. For LF files you may search with unix2dos`-ic`. It doesn't modify files. Only report.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question exactly but dos2unix **is the easiest way** to fix this.

Comment: since this is a top answer for any question regarding Windows line endings/carriage returns on Linux, I think its worth noting that you can *see* them in the terminal with the command `cat -v somefile.txt`; they show up as `^M`

Answer (score 226, accepted):

grep probably isn't the tool you want for this.  It will print a line for every matching line in every file.  Unless you want to, say, run todos 10 times on a 10 line file, grep isn't the best way to go about it.  Using find to run file on every file in the tree then grepping through that for "CRLF" will get you one line of output for each file which has dos style line endings:

```
find . -not -type d -exec file "{}" ";" | grep CRLF
```

will get you something like:

```
./1/dos1.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
./2/dos2.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
./dos.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Comment: I'd already cracked this, but thanks anyway.

`grep -IUrl --color '^M' . | xargs -ifile fromdos 'file'`

Comment: The -l option to grep tells it to just list files (once) instead of listing the matches in each file.

Comment: Not a good solution, to depend on that (undocumented, oriented to human consumption) behaviour of `file` program. This is very fragile. For (just one) example: it doesn't work with XML files, `file` reports `XML document text` regardless of newlines type.

Comment: Refering to my previous comment, to make it somewhat more robust one can add an option `file -M /dev/null`  to tell `file` not to look into magic bytes.

Comment: @leonbloy, the option seems to be a lowercase `-m /dev/null` on my `find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2` (Ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: I like this answer the best.  I simply did ``find . -type f | xargs file | grep CRLF``

Comment: Interesting, 'no idea `grep` had that option. Useful for checking streams or individual files, but *incredibly* slow when combined with `find`. 'Better to use @StevenPenny's, lightning quick on the recursive search.

Comment: @brianz `xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option`

Comment: Best answer! Even it's pretty slow, this gives me the correct list of files!

Comment: It's not a good solution, as @leonbloy wrote. Another example: `file main.js` returns `main.js: AppleWorks Word Processor 0x3d, tabstop ruler "DEL OF", zoomed, paginated, with mail merge, 32/10 inch left margin` (without writing any "CRLF" text, so at the end that case becomes another false negative). Note: `cat -A main.js` shows a ^M at the end of each line of that file.

Comment: if you want to convert these files to use LF instead of CRLF : dos2unix `find . -not -type d -exec file "{}" ";" | grep CRLF | cut -d ":" -f1`

Answer (score 143):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to enter a literal Carriage Return character into your grep string. So:

```
grep -IUr --color "^M"
```

will work - if the `^M` there is a literal CR that you input as I suggested.

If you want the list of files, you want to add the `-l` option as well.

**Explanation**

- `-I` ignore binary files
- `-U` prevents grep from stripping CR characters. By default it does this it if it decides it's a text file.
- `-r` read all files under each directory recursively.

Comment: As a quick hack that would work but I think human readbale solution would be: grep $'\r' /bash shell only/ or grep `printf '\r'`

Comment: @akostadinov +1, But backticks got interpreted out of your comment ;) The second option would, in other words, be **`grep $(printf '\r')`**. But for most practical uses involving bash, I would stick with `$'\r'`.

Comment: Note: The option `-U` is only relevant for Windows (or cygwin), but it's critical there. On Windows, the command will not work without it.

Comment: What is the point of option `-I`? By the manual, it seems to me that binary files are considered as non-matching. Shouldn't the combination of `-I` and `-U` (which enforce the binary type) result in all files being considered as non-matching?

Comment: You mention the '-l' flag as an add-on option, but I think it should be included in the primary answer because the question essentially asks for a list of files.  Also, it results in a faster search.

Comment: @arr_sea and it has the benefit that you actually see something when stdout is a tty. Without the  `-l` the trailing CRs just wipe out the lines to the beginning.

Comment: On Unix, `-U` seems to cancel the `-I`. I used `grep -Ilr $'\r' .` (using `-l`, as I only wanted filenames).

Comment: This prints files that start with an M on the first line...

Comment: The `"^M"` gets interpreted as a regex, matching on `M` characters at the start of a line.

Comment: If you enter the string as `^M`, it will match `M` at the start of a line. However that's not what the answer is suggesting: the answer is suggesting entering the search string as `Ctrl`+`V`, `Ctrl`+`M`, which (at least on my terminal emulator) will enter a carriage return control character; it looks identical to a separate `^` and `M`, but that's just how the control character gets rendered.

Answer (score 68):

Using RipGrep (depending on your shell, you might need to quote the last argument):

```
rg -l \r
```

```
-l, --files-with-matches
Only print the paths with at least one match.
```

https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep

Comment: This doesn't seem to give the correct answer, it gives me all files

Comment: @mcarton: your edit was reverted in this post. Since this contributor is now permanently banned from the network, you are at liberty to restore your version if you wish (it's not my area of expertise, so I will leave it to you/others).

Answer (score 20):

If your version of grep supports **-P (--perl-regexp)** option, then

```
grep -lUP '\r$'
```

could be used.

Comment: This is very slow...

Answer (score 16):

```
# list files containing dos line endings (CRLF)

cr="$(printf "\r")"    # alternative to ctrl-V ctrl-M

grep -Ilsr "${cr}$" . 

grep -Ilsr $'\r$' .   # yet another & even shorter alternative
```

Comment: `grep -Ilsr $'\r$' ` is a nice one and doesn't rely on `file`

Answer (score 7):

`dos2unix` has a file information option which can be used to show the files that would be converted:

```sh
dos2unix -ic /path/to/file
```

To do that recursively you can use `bash`’s `globstar` option, which for the current shell is enabled with `shopt -s globstar`:

```sh
dos2unix -ic **      # all files recursively
dos2unix -ic **/file # files called “file” recursively
```

Alternatively you can use `find` for that:

```sh
find -type f -exec dos2unix -ic {} +            # all files recursively (ignoring directories)
find -name file -exec dos2unix -ic {} + # files called “file” recursively
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use file command in unix. It gives you the character encoding of the file along with line terminators.

```
$ file myfile
myfile: ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators
$ file myfile | grep -ow CRLF
CRLF
```

Answer (score 2):

The query was search... I have a similar issue... somebody submitted mixed line
endings into the version control, so now we have a bunch of files with `0x0d`
`0x0d` `0x0a` line endings. Note that

```
grep -P '\x0d\x0a'
```

finds all lines, whereas

```
grep -P '\x0d\x0d\x0a'
```

and

```
grep -P '\x0d\x0d'
```

finds no lines so there may be something "else" going on inside grep
when it comes to line ending patterns... unfortunately for me!

Answer (score 1):

If, like me, your minimalist unix doesn't include niceties like the **file** command, and backslashes in your **grep** expressions just don't cooperate, try this:

```
$ for file in `find . -type f` ; do
> dump $file | cut -c9-50 | egrep -m1 -q ' 0d| 0d'
> if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then echo $file ; fi
> done
```

Modifications you may want to make to the above include:

- tweak the **find** command to locate only the files you want to scan
- change the **dump** command to **od** or whatever file dump utility you have
- confirm that the **cut** command includes both a leading and trailing space as well as just the hexadecimal character output from the **dump** utility
- limit the **dump** output to the first 1000 characters or so for efficiency

For example, something like this may work for you using **od** instead of **dump**:

```
 od -t x2 -N 1000 $file | cut -c8- | egrep -m1 -q ' 0d| 0d|0d$'
```