# How to use fgets properly in a structure?

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

I can't work out what's the problem with my code. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    

#define N 20

typedef struct _dog {
    char dogName[N],ownerName[N];
    int dogAge;
} Dog;

int main() {
    //Dynamic array
    int size;
    printf("Number of dogs: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    Dog *dog = (Dog*)malloc(sizeof(Dog)*size);
    printf("\n");
    //Input
    int i;
    printf("Please provide the data: [dogName][ownerName][dogAge] :\n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
        fgets(dog[i].dogName, sizeof(dog[i].dogName), stdin);
        fgets(dog[i].ownerName, sizeof(dog[i].ownerName), stdin);
        scanf("%d", &dog[i].dogAge);
    }
    //Output
    printf("\nYou provided the following data:\n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
        printf("Dog Name: %s\nOwner Name: %s\nDog Age: %d\n", dog[i].dogName, dog[i].ownerName, dog[i].dogAge);
    }

    free(dog);
    return 0;
}
```

The task is pretty easy, you have to make a database but the dogs and owners can have two or more names, so that's why i try to use fget. But the output looks awful: (And the first Dog name part is usually blank)

```
You provided the following data:
Dog Name: 

Owner Name: Doggy 1

Dog Age: 0
Dog Name: Big Dick

Owner Name: 2

Dog Age: 0
```

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138246/how-to-implement-gets-or-fgets-while-using-structure-pointer) but didn't help me.

The input I used:

```
Doggy 1
Big Dick
2
Doggy 2
```

It's ended after Doggy 2.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Could you show your input, please?

Comment: @cad Added! But it seems we've found the main problem.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thanks, I will read the post!

Comment: @M.Carver Please do not add the answer in the question. Also, you can read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244062), if it helps. ;)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thanks for the clarification, that's what I tried to find. You readin' my mind. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are leaving a newline from your last `scanf()` which is a *valid* input for the `fgets()`. Change

```
scanf("%d", &size);
```

to

```
scanf("%d%*c", &size);
```

to *consume and discard* the trailing newline due to the press of <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key after entering the number of dogs.

The same goes for the `dogAge` variable scanning, too, inside the lop.

Related, quoting the `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.2, `fscanf()`

> Trailing white space (including new-line characters) is left unread unless matched by a
>   directive. [...]

so, the `newline` (`'\n'`), the *trailing white space*, is left unread in the input buffer.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. I've added the code at the size part but it seems I've still got a bug in my code in the loop where i use scanf. If I understand right the scanf in the loop creates a newline too?

UPDATE: I've added %d%*c at the scanf in the loop, now works like a charm. :) Is there a better way to consume newlines after scanf or I have to use this all the time?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I downvoted it. No offense please, but I tested it and it does not work. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Elyasin I did not test the functionality, but I see no reason for this to fail. Can you share your test please?

Comment: Both @Elyasin and Sourav Ghosh  answer is working, now i understand what was the problem. Thanks for both of you! UPDATE: I used %d%*c at both scanf in code, and works the same as getchar();

Comment: Oh dear, I retested it and it works. I'm sorry, my bad :-(

Comment: Our interactions might have interleaved. In the beginning you forgot to mention the scanf in the inner loop. That's when my test failed. Now that I did it again it works after the edit it works. The answer is correct I think (y)

Comment: @Elyasin ha ha. I did not forget, I thought it was understood. However, later I thought of adding the last line too, and see, _it helps_ . :)

Answer (score 3):

Add a `getchar()` after the `scanf(...)` calls.

As in the other answer(s) mentioned. `scanf` consumes the recognized characters according to format, but leaves the newline `\n` in `stdin`. With `getchar` you consume it and subsequent reads from `stdin` should not *get confused*.

Comment: @Elyasin  If I add getchar(); after the two scanf it works too, thanks for the help.  You guys rock!