# looping over a fgets

Tags: c, loops, fgets

***EDIT***
Sorry, seems I didn't read enough previous questions to figure this one out. Trying out the ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34481277/how-to-use-fgets-properly-in-a-structure) led me to the `getchar()` function, which both solved the newline problem and the `while` loop.

alk's suggestion in the comments didn't seem to work at all, I could hit Enter as many times as I wanted and it wasn't doing anything.

Thanks to the mod who linked the duplicate question.

++++++++++++++++++++++

So I have an assignment to do using C. One of the components is for the user to input a title. The code snippet I have so far is:

```
char accept;
char title [30];

do
{
    printf("Please enter a title for the simulation: "); 
    fgets(title,30,stdin);

    for ( i=0; i<30; i++)
    {
        if (title[i] == '\n')   
        {                       
            title [i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    };
    printf("\nContinue? (Y/N): ");
    scanf(" %c", &accept);

//***Title to be displayed at the end with rest of test conditions***
} while ((accept == 'n') || (accept== 'N'));
```

Note: The while loop is a small-scale version that will encompass the entire program to give the option of starting over.

As I understand it, the for loop will remove the newline character after the `fgets()` input, however if the `N` option is chosen the `fgets()` is being skipped over again, and I'm really not sure why.

Comment: To add up to *user3121023*'s comment: Just add another `char dummy;  scanf(" %c", &dummy);` after `scanf(" %c", &accept);`

Comment: @alk Marked dupe. :)