# How to find dos format files in a linux file system

Tags: linux, shell, find

I would like to find out which of my files in a directory are dos text files (as opposed to unix text files). Specifically, these are files that, when opened in Vim, the bottom bar will say something like `"filename.php" [dos] [noeol]`

I've tried `find . -name "*.php" | xargs grep ^M -l`, but I don't get reliable results. In particular, it doesn't detect certain dos files that don't have `^M` characters in them.

Is there a better alternative?

Comment: ... How exactly is it not reliable?

Comment: @ignacio What bvbp says. That is, i want to be able to find the property of the file rather than what the file contains

Comment: But it isn't a property of the file, it's what the file contains.

Comment: @ignacio I have a bunch of dos files with no ^M chars in them... maybe i'm missing something

Comment: If it has no CRs then it's not a DOS format file.

Comment: but vim reports to me that it is. so i'm confused

Comment: @superspace, vim will detect a file as DOS if _every_ line has CRLF otherwise it's UNIX. I'm not sure why you think those files aren't actually DOS format unless it's the missing `^M` characters in vim's display, which is not a reliable indicator. See my answer update for the reason why, and the tool you should use to find out for certain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you search for files containing DOS line endings (CRLF) with grep on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73833/how-do-you-search-for-files-containing-dos-line-endings-crlf-with-grep-on-linu)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure what you mean exactly by "not reliable" but you may want to try:

```
find . -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l '^M$'
```

This uses the more *atrocious-filenames-with-spaces-in-them-friendly* options and only finds carriage returns immediately before the end of line.

Keep in mind that the `^M` is a single <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> character, not *two* characters.

And also that it'll list files where even *one* line is in DOS mode, which is probably what you want anyway since those would have been UNIX files mangled by a non-UNIX editor.

---

Based on your update that vim is reporting your files as DOS format:

If vim *is* reporting it as DOS format, then *every* line ends with `CRLF`. That's the way vim works. If even *one* line doesn't have `CR`, then it's considered UNIX format and the `^M` characters are visible in the buffer. If it's all DOS format, the `^M` characters are not displayed:

> Vim will look for both dos and unix line endings, but Vim has a built-in preference for the unix format.
>   
>   - If all lines in the file end with CRLF, the dos file format will be applied, meaning that each CRLF is removed when reading the lines into a buffer, and the buffer 'ff' option will be dos.
>   - If one or more lines end with LF only, the unix file format will be applied, meaning that each LF is removed (but each CR will be present in the buffer, and will display as ^M), and the buffer 'ff' option will be unix.

If you *really* want to know what's in the file, don't rely on a too-smart tool like vim :-)

Use:

```
od -xcb input_file_name | less
```

and check the line endings yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your response, ^M and ^M$ doesn't seem to return any more or less results for me

Answer (score 19):

How about:

```
find . -name "*.php" | xargs file | grep "CRLF"
```

I don't think it is reliable to try and use `^M` to try and find the files.

Comment: This is more like what I had in mind (that is, to find the property of the file rather than the content of the file). Unfortunately, a whole bunch of dos php files returned as "PHP script text" when passed through the *file* command instead of something about CRLF

Comment: for me this answer worked while the accepted answer did not work!

Answer (score 2):

i had good luck with

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec grep -Pl "\r" {} \;
```

Comment: This is more or less like the accepted answer, except it uses exec instead of xargs. I found xargs to be significantly faster, in this case at least.

Answer (score 1):

This is much like your original solution; therefore, it's possibly more easy for you to remember:

```
find . -name "*.php" | xargs grep "\r" -l
```

**Thought process:**

In VIM, to remove the ^M you type:

```
 %s:/^M//g
```

Where ^ is your Ctrl key and M is the ENTER key.  But I could never remember the keys to type to print that sequence, so I've always removed them using:

```
 %s:/\r//g
```

So my deduction is that the \r and ^M are equivalent, with the former being easier to remember to type.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunately does not add anything to what i already have... I do use the same method to remove ^M if i'm in vim and use fromdos when i'm outside

Answer (score 1):

If your `dos2unix` command has the `-i` option, you can use that feature to find files in a directory that have DOS line breaks.

```
$ man dos2unix
.
.
.
     -i[FLAGS], --info[=FLAGS] FILE ...
           Display file information. No conversion is done.

    The following information is printed, in this order:
    number of DOS line breaks,
    number of Unix line breaks,
    number of Mac line breaks,
    byte order mark,
    text or binary, file name.
.
.
.
Optionally extra flags can be set to change the (-i) output.
.
.
.
           c   Print only the files that would be converted.
```

The following one-liner script reads:

- `find` all files in this directory tree,
- run `dos2unix` on all files to determine the files to be changed,
- run `dos2unix` on files to be changed

`$ find . -type f | xargs -d '\n' dos2unix -ic | xargs -d '\n' dos2unix`

Answer (score 1):

I've been using `cat -e` to see what line endings files have.

Using `^M` as a single <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> character didn't really work out for me (it works as if I just press <kbd>return</kbd>, without actually inserting the non-printable `^M` line ending — tested with `echo '`<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>`' | cat -e`), so what I ended up doing will probably seem too much, but it did the job nevertheless:

```
grep '$' *.php | cat -e | grep '\^M\$' | sed 's/:.*//' | uniq
```

, where

- the first `grep` just prepends filenames to each line of each file (can be replaced with `awk '{print FILENAME, $0}'`, but `grep` worked faster on my set of files);
- `cat -e` explicitly prints non-printable line endings;
- the second `grep` finds lines ending with `^M$`, and `^M` *are two characters*;
- the `sed` part keeps only the file names (can be replaced with `cut -d ':' -f 1`);
- `uniq` just keeps each file name once.

Answer (score 0):

GNU find

```
find . -type f -iname "*.php"  -exec file "{}" + | grep CRLF
```

I don't know what you want to do after you find those DOS php files, but if you want to convert them to unix format, then

```
find . -type f -iname "*.php"  -exec dos2unix "{}" +;
```

will suffice. There's no need to specifically check whether they are DOS files or not.

Comment: this is a similar method to @pvpb ... but it is still lacking... not returning the results I expected (because all the PHP files report that they are "PHP script text" files)

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer vim to tell you which files are in this format you can use the following script:

```
"use this script to check which files are in dos format according to vim
"use: in the folder that you want to check
"create a file, say res.txt
"> vim -u NONE --noplugins res.txt
"> in vim: source this_script.vim

python << EOF
import os
import vim

cur_buf =  vim.current.buffer

IGNORE_START = ''.split()
IGNORE_END = '.pyc .swp .png ~'.split()

IGNORE_DIRS = '.hg .git dd_ .bzr'.split()

for dirpath, dirnames, fnames in os.walk(os.curdir):
  for dirn in dirnames:
    for diri in IGNORE_DIRS:
      if dirn.endswith(diri):
        dirnames.remove(dirn)
        break
  for fname in fnames:
    skip = False
    for fstart in IGNORE_START:
      if fname.startswith(fstart):
        skip = True
    for fend in IGNORE_END:
      if fname.endswith(fend):
        skip = True
    if skip is True:
      continue
    fname = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
    vim.command('view {}'.format(fname))
    curr_ff = vim.eval('&ff')
    if vim.current.buffer != cur_buf:
      vim.command('bw!')
    if curr_ff == 'dos':
      cur_buf.append('{} {}'.format(curr_ff, fname))
EOF
```

your vim needs to be compiled with python (python is used to loop over the files in the folder, there is probably an easier way of doing this, but I don't really know it....