# Running the Python Code on Hadoop Failed

Tags: python, hadoop-streaming

I have tried to follow the instructions on this page:
 http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/

```
$bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.4.jar -input /user/root/wordcountpythontxt -output /user/root/wordcountpythontxt-output -mapper /user/root/wordcountpython/mapper.py -reducer /user/root/wordcountpython/reducer.py -file /user/root/mapper.py -file /user/root/reducer.py
```

It says

```
File: /user/root/mapper.py does not exist, or is not readable.
Streaming Command Fail
```

When i browsed through the url:jobdetails.jsp/

i found lot of exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:34)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/user/root/wordcountpython/mapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:214)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:53)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:91)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
    ... 24 more
```

i am not able to fix it out pls help me to run the python pgm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you checked the instructions carefully on the [link](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/),

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-*streaming*.jar -file /home/hduser/mapper.py -mapper /home/hduser/mapper.py -file /home/hduser/reducer.py -reducer /home/hduser/reducer.py -input /user/hduser/gutenberg/* -output /user/hduser/gutenberg-output
```

there it clearly shows there is no need to copy the mapper.py and reducer.py to the HDFS, you can link both the files from the local filesystem: as /path/to/mapper. I am sure you can avoid the above error.

Comment: @studhadoop If the solution solves your problem, you could accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check that you don't have a dos-style new line after your #! line within mapper.py. If you do, hadoop may not be able to find your python interpreter since it'll see an extra CR. E.g. /usr/local/bin/python^M instead of /usr/local/bin/python where ^M is CR. Try dos2unix command on both your mapper and reducer.

Comment: how will i do that to mapper and reducer

Comment: ...sorry... just run `dos2unix mapper.py`, assuming you have dos2unix installed. And then the same for your reducer.py. You could grep for the dos new line to confirm it's there before and gone afterwards: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73833/how-do-you-search-for-files-containing-dos-line-endings-crlf-with-grep-under-l]. Also, if this is your problem then you might consider changing how your editor saves files. E.g. if you use Eclipse the default is for dos-style new lines

Answer (score 1):

It seems problem is in line.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/user/root/wordcountpython/mapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Will you please check file `/user/root/wordcountpython/mapper.py` exists or not. If it exists then what is the permission to that file.

User by which you are running hadoop has the permission to execute and read this file?