# Hadoop: Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I have Hadoop installed and working perfectly because I run the word count example and it works great. Now I tried to move forward and do some more real examples. My example is done in  [this website as Example 2 (Average Salaries by each department)](http://datasciencecheetah.com/?p=472) . I am using the same code from the website and [this data](https://data.baltimorecity.gov/City-Government/Baltimore-City-Employee-Salaries-FY2014/2j28-xzd7)

**mapper.py**

```
#!usr/bin/Python
# mapper.py
import csv
import sys
reader = csv.reader(sys.stdin, delimiter=',')
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter='\t')
for row in reader:
    agency = row[3]
    annualSalary = row[5][1:].strip()
    print '{0}\t{1}'.format(agency, annualSalary)
```

**reducer.py**

```
#!usr/bin/Python
# reducer.py 
import csv
import sys
agency_salary_sum = 0
current_agency = None
n_occurences = 0
for row in sys.stdin:
    data_mapped = row.strip().split("\t")
    if len(data_mapped) != 2:
        # Something has gone wrong. Skip this line.
        continue
    agency, salary = data_mapped
    try: salary = float(salary)
    except: continue
    if agency == current_agency:
        agency_salary_sum += salary
        n_occurences += 1
    else:
        if current_agency:
            print '{0}\t{1}'.format(current_agency, agency_salary_sum/n_occurences)
            n_occurences = 0
        current_agency = agency
        agency_salary_sum = salary
if current_agency == agency:
    print '{0}\t{1}'.format(current_agency, agency_salary_sum / n_occurences)
```

Following the command I used to run my job

```
$ bin/hadoop jar python/hadoop-streaming-2.7.0.jar -file python/salaries/mapper.py -mapper python/salaries/mapper.py -file python/salaries/reducer.py -reducer python/salaries/reducer.py -input new-input/ -output output
```

Following is the trace I am getting

```
18/07/02 12:20:03 WARN streaming.StreamJob: -file option is deprecated, please use generic option -files instead.
packageJobJar: [python/salaries/mapper.py, python/salaries/reducer.py, /tmp/hadoop-unjar4765938201803407949/] [] /tmp/streamjob3060992493780265460.jar tmpDir=null
18/07/02 12:20:05 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
18/07/02 12:20:06 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
18/07/02 12:20:07 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
18/07/02 12:20:07 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
18/07/02 12:20:07 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1530451183103_0017
18/07/02 12:20:07 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1530451183103_0017
18/07/02 12:20:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://98f81ca7cf43:8088/proxy/application_1530451183103_0017/
18/07/02 12:20:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1530451183103_0017
18/07/02 12:20:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1530451183103_0017 running in uber mode : false
18/07/02 12:20:16 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/07/02 12:20:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1530451183103_0017_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:449)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1530451183103_0017/container_1530451183103_0017_01_000003/./mapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
        ... 24 more

18/07/02 12:20:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1530451183103_0017_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:449)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1530451183103_0017/container_1530451183103_0017_01_000002/./mapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
        ... 24 more

18/07/02 12:20:40 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1530451183103_0017_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:449)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1530451183103_0017/container_1530451183103_0017_01_000004/./mapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
        ... 24 more

18/07/02 12:20:41 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1530451183103_0017_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:449)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1530451183103_0017/container_1530451183103_0017_01_000005/./mapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
        ... 24 more

18/07/02 12:20:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1530451183103_0017_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:449)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1530451183103_0017/container_1530451183103_0017_01_000007/./mapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
        ... 24 more

18/07/02 12:20:54 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
18/07/02 12:20:54 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1530451183103_0017_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:449)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1530451183103_0017/container_1530451183103_0017_01_000008/./mapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
        ... 24 more

18/07/02 12:20:55 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/07/02 12:21:05 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
18/07/02 12:21:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1530451183103_0017 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1530451183103_0017_m_000001
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

18/07/02 12:21:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 13
        Job Counters
                Failed map tasks=7
                Killed map tasks=1
                Launched map tasks=8
                Other local map tasks=6
                Data-local map tasks=2
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=81502
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=81502
                Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=81502
                Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=83458048
        Map-Reduce Framework
                CPU time spent (ms)=0
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
18/07/02 12:21:05 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful!
Streaming Command Failed!
```

At the end it also creates an empty output folder. I really have no idea what is going wrong here. Is my approach wrong or some configuration problem? Any help in moving even slightly forward will be really appreciated.

Comment: From the stacktrace, `Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory`. Check whether the path specified for the `mapper.py` is correct and exists? Also try with absolute path.

Comment: I used the similar path for the word count problem and it worked fine. Also I double checked it. mapper.py and reducer.py exists in the specified paths

Comment: please see this link once, a similar problem has been discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353252/running-the-python-code-on-hadoop-failed

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running the below command:

```
bin/hadoop jar python/hadoop-streaming-2.7.0.jar  -mapper python/salaries/mapper.py -reducer python/salaries/reducer.py -input new-input/* -output output
```

I **removed** the '-file python/salaries/mapper.py' , '-file python/salaries/reducer.py' Options

Answer (score 0):

This might be not the case, but I believe this line is incorrect.

`#!usr/bin/Python`

It should point to correct python interpreter i.e `#!/usr/bin/python`.

If it's not correctly set, then for hadoop streaming library you have to specify python interpreter in `-mapper` or `-reducer` parameter i.e. `-mapper python python/salaries/mapper.py`

Answer (score 0):

I occur the same wrong.
you can try to sign the mapper and reducer like this:

```
-mapper '/usr/bin/python mapper.py' \
-reducer '/usr/bin/python reducer.py'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the path of python interpreter, in my case it was /usr/bin/python3

If you perform say `cd /usr/bin/python3` it should be valid path

So it could be `#!/usr/bin/python3`