# Why doesn't grep give the matching line?

Tags: grep

I've just noticed that

```
grep -rni 'a2}' *
```

does not give <s>all documents that have a string `a2}`</s> the matching line. Why is this the case?

I've tried to create a minimal example, but when I create a new file and paste the content, it fails. So I've uploaded the file to a [Git repository](https://github.com/MartinThoma/algorithms/tree/master/grep). Perhaps it's a encoding problem.

The content of the file is:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{KV-Diagramme}
\label{chap:a2}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \PsTexAbbildungOhneCaption{figures/a2-1}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "skript"
%%% End:
```

The result of `grep -rni 'a2}' *` is

```
moose@pc08 ~/Downloads/algorithms/grep $ grep -rni "a2}" *
%%% End:master: "skript"%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

but I expected

```
moose@pc08 ~/Downloads/algorithms/grep $ grep -rni "a2}" *
\label{chap:a2}
```

Why do I get this result?

Comment: I get the following output: `tmp.txt:3:\label{chap:a2}`

Comment: That's odd: I get the result you were expecting.

Comment: Me too ... same result as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file has CR line terminators so it looks a a single-line file:

```
#> file anhang-2.tex
anhang-2.tex: LaTeX document, ASCII text, with CR line terminators
```

convert it to Linux format:

```
#>  mac2unix anhang-2.tex
mac2unix: converting file anhang-2.tex to Unix format ...
#>  grep -rni 'a2}' anhang-2.tex 
3:\label{chap:a2}
```

Comment: How can I check for all `.tex` files in a folder if they have CR line terminators?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73833/how-do-you-search-for-files-containing-dos-line-endings-crlf-with-grep-on-linu

Comment: @moose, `file *tex | grep CR`

Answer (score 0):

It's because your file is using Mac OS 9 line endings. You will need to first translate to UNIX line endings. How you do so depends on your scenario but you can do one file with this:

```
tr '\r' '\n' < anhang-2.tex > anhang-2.txt
```

Then you will be able to grep that new file.

Comment: @perreal you are correct about the line termination. I just made a quick assumption. Edited answer. Thanks.