# Regular Expression: find all old PHP open tags

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find and replace all old style PHP open tags: `<?` and `<?=`. I've tried several things:

**Find all `<?` strings and replace them with `<?php` and ignore XML**

```
sudo grep -ri "<?x[^m]" --include \*.php /var/www/
```

This returns no results, so all tags that open with `<?x` are XML opening tags and should be ignored.

Then I did the same for tags that start with `<?p` but are not `<?php`

```
sudo grep -ri "<?p[^h]" --include \*.php /var/www/
```

This returned one page that I edited manually - so this won't return results anymore. So I can be sure that tags that start with `<?p` all are `<?php` and the same goes for x and xml.

```
sudo grep -ri "<?[^xp]" --include \*.php /var/www/
```

**Find more opening tags that should not be replaced**

From here on I can run the above command and see what turns up: spaces, tabs, newlines, `=` and `{` (which can be ignored). I thought that `\s` would take care of whitespace, but I still get many results back.

Trying this results in endless lists with tabs in it:

```
sudo grep -ri "<?[^xp =}\t\n\s]" --include \*.php /var/www/
```

So in the end this is not useful. I can't scan thousands of lines. What is wrong with this expression? If somewhere `<?jsp` would exist and shouldn't be replaced, I want to know this, exclude it, then get a shorter list back, and repeat this until the list is empty. That way I'm sure that I'm not going to change tags that shouldn't be changed.

**Update: ^M**

If I open the results in Vim, I see `^M`, which is a newline character. This can be escaped pasting the following directly on the commandline where `^M` is in the code below: Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to [enter a literal Carriage Return character into your grep string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73833/how-do-you-search-for-files-containing-dos-line-endings-crlf-with-grep-on-linu/73886#73886). This reduces the results to 1000 lines.

```
sudo grep -ri "<?[^xp =}\t\n\s^M]" --include \*.php /var/www/
```

**Replace the old tags**

If this expression works, I want to run a sed command and use it to replace the old opening tags.

- `<?` should become `<?php` (with ending space)
- `<?=` should become `<?php echo` (with ending space)

This would result in one or more commands like these, first replacing `<?`, then `<?=`.

```
sudo find /var/www/ -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i 's/<?[^xp=]/<?php /g' {} \;
sudo find /var/www/ -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i 's/<?=/<?php echo /g' {} \;
```

**Questions**

1. To get the search (grep) and replace (sed) working, I need to know how to exclude all whitespace. In Vim I see a `^M` character which needs to be excluded.
2. If my approach is wrong, please let me know. All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: `<?=` is not an old style php tag btw. [Starting with PHP 5.4, short echo tag <?= is always recognized and valid, regardless of the short_open_tag setting.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php). Unless you're using an ancient version of php - that last find and replace should arguably be the other way around. You need to escape your `?` characters.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I got the recommendation to replace that too, and I see in Zend Framework remarks about converting it to `<?php echo `. But this is easier, so I can leave it as it is.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't use regexes. You could use [the `token_get_all()` function](http://php.net/manual/de/function.token-get-all.php), or even [a dedicated library](https://github.com/kix/php-open-tag-fixer) for fixing these. It might even be possible with nikic's [PHP-Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) project.

Comment: It turns out that in the past it was thought that `<?=` was going to conflict with XML specs, but apparantly this is not the case anymore. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847072/php-vs-php-echo-whats-the-difference-which-one-is-better-to-use

Comment: I tried to escape `?`, but that doesn't work here. Then I get innumerable wrong results. I don't know why.

Comment: @Franz - that library doesn't work here.

Comment: Did you try using `sed -i 's/<\\?[[:space:]]/<?php /g' *.php` and `sed -i 's/<\\?=[[:space:]]/<?php echo /g' *.php`? Just curious if escaping and using a named character class can help. Acc. to documentation, the question mark in the replacement string does not have to be escaped, but in find string, '\?' actually means that the preceding character is optional.

Comment: I'm using Grep 2.6.3. I've just tried that double escape, and the single one. They result in exactly the same file size, which is 500x the size of the grep without escaping, and 499 of those 500 lines are not results that I'm looking for, like this comment line: `// Specify font`. No idea why it is like this, but it is. - BUT WAIT - you're talking sed, and I'm talking about grep. That could be the confusion. Your sed command is only about `<?` with a space following, and that is not enough for what I need.

Comment: @stribizhev - I tried single escape and each single character in all files was replaced with `<?php` behind it. I tested this on one page only. I tried the double escape - that doesn't work here. No escape seems to work.

Comment: Did you try adding `-r` option without escaping? Also, this page seems to have lots of helpful hints about sed: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Comment: Could you try `grep /var/www --include='*.php' --color -Pnre '(?sm)(?:(['\''"])(?:\\.|.)*?\1|//.*?$|/\*.*?\*/)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<\?\B'` and tell me if it correctly highlights the tags you want? (it will still find tags in a multiline comment like `/* ... <? ... */` but that's ok)

Comment: Starting from PHP 7.0, [The ASP tags <%, %>, <%=, and the script tag <script language="php"> are removed from PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php). So you may want to update this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a small Perl test here with a few files... seems to work fine. Wouldn't this do the trick for you?

```
shopt -s globstar # turn on **
perl -p -e 's/<\?=/<php echo/g;s/<\?/<php/g' so-test/**/*.php
```

- Change `so-test` for the folder you want to test on.
- Add the `-i.bak` option before `-e` to create backup files.
- Only add `-i` (without the `.bak`) to affect the files. Without `-i`, the result is printed to the console rather than written in files. Good for testing!